# Match substring in string divided by a dot

Tags: php, regex

I have following strings:

```
'sample1.sample2'
'sample1.sample2.samaple3'
```

on so on..

I want to separate values sample1, sample2 and sample3 from this string (please note the quotation mark is there).

My code:

```
$matches = [];
$regex = "'(.*?)\.(.*?)'";
$string = "'dużotekstu.tekstpokropce'";
$match = preg_match(sprintf("/^%s$/", $regex), $string, $matches);
```

works fine only for first case.

Comment: `explode ('.',trim($string,"'"))` try this

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$string = "dużotekstu.tekstpokropce";
$exp = explode(".",$string);
$output = implode(",",$exp);
```

**Output**

```
dużotekstu,tekstpokropce
```

Try with this code. it may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can trim single quotes and then a simple `explode` on dot:

```
php> $str = "'sample1.sample2.samaple3'";

php> print_r(explode('.', trim($str, "'")));
Array
(
    [0] => sample1
    [1] => sample2
    [2] => samaple3
)

php> $str = "'sample1.sample2'";

php> print_r(explode('.', trim($str, "'")));
Array
(
    [0] => sample1
    [1] => sample2
)
```

Comment: It has to be regex. In output I have to parse the entire HTML page and I want to separate only this few values.

Comment: Question has no reference of parsing HTML. As a general rule parsing HTML must be done using DOM not using regex.

Comment: Let's consider something like this: `<span>Sample text {$_LANG['sample1.sample2.sample3']} sample text text text</span>`

Comment: I will suggest use DOM to extract text from `<span>` tag then parse out `'sample1.sample2.sample3'` using string or regex function and finally use my suggested code for splitting.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you split string using `preg_split`. You can refer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_split() if it has to be a Regex:

```
$array = preg_split('/\./', $string);
```